# Preg match multiple words

Tags: php, regex

I have a pattern that looks like this:

```
$my_pattern = "/(^|[\n\r\f\t \.\,])" . $my_text . "([\n\r\f\t \.\,]|$)/iu"
```

I have several words that could be $my_text, and I am looking for a way to do a preg match for all of them.  I know I could do a foreach and change the $my_text for each iteration, but how can I do this in just one step?

So, if I had an array of `my_textes = array("my_text1", "my_text2");`  And a sentence like this:

"I look for my_text1 and also my_text2",

I would like to be able to find my_text1 and my_text2.

Thanks!

Comment: use preg_match_all: http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php

Comment: Do you want to match strings that contain ALL OF my_textes words or ANY OF my_textes words?

Comment: $my_pattern = "/(^|[\s.,])" . $my_text . "([\s.,]|$)/iu"; your pattern can be written like so btw. You don't need to escape the period or comma since they are inside the character class and \s will equal any whitespace character. =o)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turn the regexp into something like this:

```
$my_pattern = "/(^|[\s.,])(my_text1|my_text2)([\s.,]|$)/iu";
```

The implode function will help you here.

[Code example](http://ideone.com/08ikHk)